# NLA editor does not save keyframe changes

Tags: nla-editor

I tried to edit my animation like this:

1. Click on the action strip I want to modify
2. Press the Tab key to bring this strip up in the Action Editor
3. The strip turns green and the action is shown in the action editor
4. In the Action Editor move the timeline to the keyframe I want to change
5. In the left column of the Action Editor change the value of "X Location" to a new value. The object moves to this location in the scene.
6. Click on the action strip and press Tab again to revert to normal mode
7. The change I made to the action is immediately reverted.

I watched various tutorials and I can't see anything strange in what I am doing. I also tried a few variants such as Grabbing the model and inserting a new keyframe, or duplicating an existing keyframe but all of these changes are reverted as soon as I press Tab or move to another keyframe.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hello, could you please share your file (only keep the useful elements): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Eventually I deleted all animations and started over. The second time I was able to get it working. I guess that somehow I managed to get it into a messed up state - probably because I was learning and doing things the wrong way.

Comment: I think the NLA editor still needs some polishing. For example I still get the situation where clicking on an Action Strip and hitting Tab does not bring up the action in Action Editor. In that case I just select the action in the drop-down then unlink the action when I am done editing it.
There is still al lot about the NLA that is very awkward and counter-intuitive.

Comment: no, you must miss something but the interaction between Dope Sheet and NLA is a bit hard to understand at the beginning (actually I heard there were some bugs but it's rare)

Comment: I really think that the Action Editor should be deprecated and the functionality it provides needs to be part of NLA Editor, i.e. there could be an expander on the action strip that opens up the keyframes below the action strip. This would make it so much easier to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Another gotcha is that I can add actions to a track that act on another object and they just do nothing when I run the animation. If I want to control multiple objects in one track I have to create an armature track and put bones into the various objects - which is highly counter intuitive.

Comment: NLA has its own logic that is a bit hard to understand at the beginning, but it's a bit hard to explain through Blender Stack Exchange, you should follow some tutorials on this matter. Of course it should be improved but it already works pretty well

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue, especially with older versions of Blender, one of the chief reasons this can happen is if you're trying to edit a keyframe past the designated *End Frame* listed in the "Action Clip" header of the Properties menu. To fix:

1. Simply press the "N" key in the *NLA Editor* to open the Properties menu and look for the "Action Clip" header.
2. Make sure the *End Frame* is set to a value beyond the frame you're currently trying to keyframe.
3. Make sure that your adjustments to this value don't also alter the "Scale" setting (which under most circumstances should remain 1.0).

In more recent versions of Blender, you may need to press the "Strip" tab first in the Properties menu to find the "Action Clip" header and make this adjustment.